# JAVA FX ImageView only loads certain images when launched

Tags: javafx, imageview

I'm currently working on a poker application for fun and I've encountered another issue when trying to work with imageviews.

Right now my structure for my images is the following:
*JavaFXApplication1\src\images*

that "images" folder contains two more folders, one being "cards" and the other "playerImages".
Here is a screenshot of it also:[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Sog.png)

Currently I am using a document relative path within scene builder to initially load the images for each of the cards and players. for each of the cards, the imagepath initially is "@..\images\cards\back.png" which is set in scenebuilder. this method works perfectly fine when launching the application. however, for the player images next to the cards, i have "@..\images\playerImages\player1.png" for example and this doesnt work for some reason.

In scenebuilder the "player1.png" image shows up where it should, but disappears when i launch everything.

I read through [Images not showing on launch by the main, but showed on Scene builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944885/images-not-showing-on-launch-by-the-main-but-showed-on-scene-builder) but Im not not sure the solution for that is the same for me, as my images are in my source folder.

I tried using the fx:id and setting the image manually in my controller class, but was receiving an error stating that my input stream was null.

I also tried just adding "player1.png" to my root images folder and using that path, and that still didnt work. yet, when I change the player1 image path to anything in the cards folder it works. I dont understand why it works for the images in the cards folder but not in the playerImages folder. Both of those folders are in the same location.

I apologize if this was already answered somewhere else and i am too oblivious to see it, but any insight into this seemingly simple problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a similar project structure:

```
--main
  --java
    --src
    --resources
      --images
       --cards
         back.png
       --players
         player1.png
```

you can set images from resources in your java-code. But you need to use `getResources()`

For example:

```
@FXML
private ImageView imageView;

Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/players/player1.png"));
imageView = new ImageView(image);
```

Of course directory "resources: shuild be marked as resources root

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been using this method originally actually. I dont know why, but it only seems to work with certain images. I downloaded a bunch of different pictures from google to use alternatively, and only one of them works. They are all .pngs but vary in size and width. I tried both bigger and smaller images from the one that does work and I cannot figure out why they arent working as well. What is so special about the ones that do work?

Comment: When I pass the path to an image that works the code executes and changes the picture, but when I try any of the other images I receive a **java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null** error, yet the filename I am passign is correct, and in scenebuilder, the pictures are there. Only upon execution do they seem to disappear.

Comment: I think I figured it out. From within netbeans, after manually expanding the images folder, I noticed the filename that works is stored as "player1.png" where every other image is stored as "player#.PNG". I didnt know that whether 
 the filename **extension** was in upper or lower case mattered, as I have never encountered this issue before.